# How could do some http requests just from the server side in Angular Universal

Tags: angular, angular-universal, server-rendering

I'm implementing Angular Universal over an Angular project to hide some http requests, but in my research, I found that I can't hide those with the way provided by Angular. Did someone try to do the http request in the express engine an retrieve the data?

The target is a very large Angular 5 project (I know.. If I wanted to do the http requests from the server, I wouldn't use Angular but I didn't begin the project)

I applied the configuration recommended by Angular in this article:
https://angular.io/guide/universal

I want to hide some requests from the client

Comment: You should be able to in principle by only performing this call from module that is just referenced inside your server.module.ts file. Not sure about the old version of Angular you’re using though.. SSR wasn’t really solid in version 5 if I remember correctly..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot. Only initial page will be rendered using angular universal; once that page is loaded the client side angular application takes over and then you've got SPA navigation, with ajax calls to your API.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the HTTP calls server side and then send that state through with your page using the [TransferHTTP](https://github.com/angular/universal/blob/master/docs/transfer-http.md) library.

https://medium.com/@alireza.mirian/reusing-server-side-http-responses-in-front-end-when-using-ssr-in-angular-970d3efaea59